# Error when I use getServerSideProps: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next, urql

I am using an Urql client to make a query to my graphql server. My query looks like this:

```
const username = () => {
  const { t: translation } = useTranslation(["common", "profile"]);

  const { query, locale } = useRouter();
  const username = query.username;
  const [{ data: userProfileData }] = useUserProfileQuery({
    variables: {
      username: username as string,
    },
    pause: isServer || !username,
  });
  const userProfile = userProfileData?.userProfile;

  return (
    <Text>{userProfile.name}</Text>
  );
};

export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient, { ssr: false })(username);
```

This would be fine, but because I am using the `next-i18next` library to localise my website, I have to add the `getServerSideProps` function.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale, locales}: any) => {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(
        locale,
        ["common", "profile", "settings"],
        null,
        locales
      )),
    },
  };
};
```

This all works fine, but it means I can't server-side render my page by setting ssr to true like the following:

```
export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient, { ssr: false })(username);
```

My goal is to make the query on the `useUserProfileQuery` server.

[I read the following guide: `https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/server-side-rendering/#ssr-with-getstaticprops-or-getserversideprops`](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/advanced/server-side-rendering/#ssr-with-getstaticprops-or-getserversideprops). Which suggested that I do the query in `getServerSideProps`. As a result, the new `getServerSideProps` function looks like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ locale, locales, query }: any) => {
  const ssrCache = ssrExchange({ isClient: false });
  const client = initUrqlClient(createUrqlClient(ssrCache), false);
  if (client)
    await client
      .query(UserProfileDocument, {
        username: query.username,
      })
      .toPromise();

  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(
        locale,
        ["common", "profile", "settings"],
        null,
        locales
      )),
      urqlState: ssrCache.extractData(),
    },
  };
};
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to return `userProfile` in `getServerProps` and remove the query from the `username` function.

Here's what the new `getServerProps` looks like

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  locale,
  locales,
  query,
}: any) => {
  const ssrCache = ssrExchange({ isClient: false });
  const client = initUrqlClient(createUrqlClient(ssrCache), false);
  let userProfile = null;
  if (client)
    userProfile = await client
      .query(UserProfileDocument, {
        username: query.username,
      })
      .toPromise();

  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(
        locale,
        ["common", "profile", "settings"],
        null,
        locales
      )),
      userProfile: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userProfile?.data?.userProfile)),
    },
  };
};
```

This is what the new `username` function looks like

```
const username = ({locale, userProfile}: any) => {
  const { t: translation } = useTranslation(["common", "profile"]);

  return (
    <Text>{userProfile.name}</Text>
  );
};
export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient, { ssr: false })(username);
```